# How do these AWS performance metrics of the same load test fit together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, load-testing, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS to set up a simple proof of concept. It consists of an AWS lambda function connected to a serverless RDS instance. The lambda function can be called via an API Gateway. I decided to load test it by using [this AWS CloudFormation template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/welcome.html).

```
CloudWatch Lambda metrics:      314 ms average duration
CloudWatch API Gateway metrics: 230 ms average latency
Load test:                      891 ms average response time
```

[Duration metrics definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html)

[Latency metric definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html)

My questions:

1. Shouldn't the average latency of the API Gateway be higher than the average duration of the Lambda function?
2. Do you have a possible explanation for the difference to the average response time reported by the load test?

Everything is hosted in eu-central-1.

Comment: Do API Gateway or Lambda show throttling in any of their metrics?

Comment: No throttling. Even if there was, I don't think it would help explaining the deltas in the metrics, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: If a Lambda reaches its max concurrent invocations technically it would reject the invocation to API Gateway resulting in API Gateway returning a 502 error. This would also be near instance which would result in the API Gateway latency being significantly less for that request.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation! I just double checked, no throttling on lambda and no errors on the API Gateway according to CloudWatch.

Comment: Does API Gateway have caching enabled?

Comment: Also no :/ All setting are default.